# Combing two different tables together for a query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, mysql-5.7

I have two tables that share some column names but I don't really care about that.

I just want to combine the two tables and sort by created_at date. For one of the columns I'd like to populate a default value when its coming from table b

I would take one table like this

| id | created | title | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2021-01-01 | "Hello" | Welcome message |
| 16 | 2021-01-03 | "Hi" | Welcome message |

combine it with a table like this

| id | created | link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2021-01-02 | so.ca |

and I'm looking for something like this

| id | created | link | title | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-01 | null | "Hello" | Welcome message |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | so.ca | null | tableB item |
| 2 | 2021-01-03 | null | "Hi" | Welcome message |

How do I best go about this? I only need this table for the query. I'm using rails and mysql 5.7. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1), created, link, title, category
from ((select ids, created, null as link, title, category
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select id, created, link, null, 'tableB item'
       from table2
      )
      order by created
     ) tt cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
```

Comment: I'd do the row_number as an "each_with_index" thing, and look at creating the `select` as a `view`, (so that I could use a model to reference it in Ruby). depending on if this is a one-off merge, or a repeated thing